# Is it possible to listen to an event of a wallet/address receiving fund

Tags: ethers.js, wallet-transfer, event-handling

I am trying to dynamically update the balance of an ethereum address in database. For this i want to setup such a scenario that whenever that address receives ethers, an event or call back should be triggered.

How can I achieve this using ethers.js?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve that easily with ethers since is not a blockchain explorer but a library to read and send transactions but not all hope is lost, you might want to look at [Alchemy Api's](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/api-overview) or [Infura apis](https://docs.infura.io/infura/networks/ethereum/json-rpc-methods), they've got a lot of functional apis that might help your purposes

Keep in mind these facts:

- EOA Addresses (a regular wallet) does not emit events when getting
  ETH transfered
- Contracts that transfer ETH or any token might implement 'events' in
  their code; these events you can track, for that you might want to
  use a service like [alchemy notify](https://www.alchemy.com/notify) which can keep track of events
  emitted by contracts